# Convert result within statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following simple query

```
SELECT TOP 1 name FROM months
```

which returns name = "march". Is it possible to convert this result? Instead of "march" I want name = "3". Is SQL capable of doing such things? I'm using a MSSQL database.

*[update] Corrected the query. While writing this simple example I mixed it up with MySQL [/update]*

Comment: What columns does the `months` table have?

Comment: LIMIT has no meaning in MS Sql server.  I think you're mistaken.

Comment: `LIMIT` is not valid T-SQL and is not understood by SQL-Server. It is a MySql construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to map a fixed set of input values against a fixed set of output values, `CASE WHEN` is your friend:

```
SELECT
  CASE name
    WHEN 'january'  THEN 1
    WHEN 'february' THEN 2
    WHEN 'march'    THEN 3
    /* ... */
  END as num
FROM
  months
```

Comment: PS: This is standard SQL systax that will work across different DB engines.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want month number, you could do this:

```
SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN name = 'January' then 1
      WHEN name = 'February' then 2
      WHEN name = 'March' then 3
      WHEN name = 'April' then 4
      WHEN name = 'May' then 5
      WHEN name = 'June' then 6
      WHEN name = 'July' then 7
      WHEN name = 'August' then 8
      WHEN name = 'September' then 9
      WHEN name = 'October' then 10
      WHEN name = 'November' then 11
      WHEN name = 'December' then 12
   END month_num
FROM months
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're really using SQL server, you could try the following

```
SELECT TOP 1 MONTH(CAST('01 ' + name + ' 2000' AS DATETIME))
FROM months
```

But as others have said, your use of the `LIMIT` keyword suggests you might be on another RDBMS

Comment: Also, for merely twelve predictable values, building a string, casting it to `DATETIME` and then passing it through `MONTH()` will most definitely be slower than `CASE WHEN`, and it will blow up when there is a month with a typo in it.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle we use DECODE. But I think in SQL Server you have to go with CASE. Example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name = 'March' THEN '3' 
            WHEN name = 'April' THEN '4' 
            ELSE 'something else' 
       END
FROM months
```

Comment: I can agree with that. CASE is more readable than DECODE. Actually the very best would be a JOIN or SUB-SELECT with a "lookup-table". That prevents hardcoding. But in specific case it might even be a data formatting issue as I judge from some other up voted answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just for variety

```
SELECT 
CEILING(CHARINDEX(name,'January   February  March     April     May       June      July      August    September October   November  December'
COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as )/10.0) 
 month_num
 FROM months
```

Comment: might want to add LOWER in front of both name and the searchstring - Nick's original question was based on the value 'march'.

Comment: @Mark - I've lobbed a `COLLATE` in there to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using SQLServer's date conversion functions, like so:

```
select TOP 1 datepart(month,convert(datetime, left(name,3) + ' 01, 01', 107))
FROM months
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you'll be able to do is a CASE statement.

```
select case name
           when 'January' then 1
           when 'February' then 2
           ...
           when 'December' then 12
       end as MonthNumber
   from months
```